# Импортирование классов и их взаимодействие в основном файле (python3, PyQt5)

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с импортированием `классов`.

В программе есть **`Основное окно`** с выбором разных программ (кнопки с открыванием других окон) и, собственно, окна других Программ (в примере будет только одна программа - "**`Программа Kata`**").

Основное окно - это основной файл, каждая другое окно - тоже отдельный файл. В основной файл я импортирую классы из файлов остальных программ.

В **`Программе Kata`** есть два окна. Окно для оператора ввода и окно для отображения информации, введенной в окне ввода оператора.
Для каждого окна по два класса. Первые классы - это `UI` из *Qt Designer*, Вторые классы - расчеты.

Основной файл я назвал "`mail`", файл с Программой Kata - "`Kata`"

Я смог составить код так, что у меня может запуститься программа, производится расчет по нажатию кнопок и отображение результата в `Окне оператора ввода`, но `Окно для отображения информации` данные не отправляются. 
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться

**Файл "mail"**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Kata import KataMainWindow
from Kata import KataMainWindow_Ui
from Kata import KataSecondWindow
from Kata import KataSecondWindow_Ui

# Create application
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

# Create form and init UI Kata
Form11 = QtWidgets.QWidget()

ui_kata12 = KataMainWindow_Ui()
ui_kata12.setupUi(Form11)

ui_kata11 = KataMainWindow()
ui_kata11.setupUi(Form11)

Form12 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
ui_kata21 = KataSecondWindow_Ui()
ui_kata21.setupUi_Kata2(Form12)

ui_kata22 = KataSecondWindow()
ui_kata22.setupUi_Kata2(Form12)


class Ui_Form0(object):
    def setupUi0(self, Form0):
        Form0.setObjectName("Form00")
        Form0.setEnabled(True)
        Form0.resize(400, 200)
        Form0.setWindowOpacity(1.0)
        Form0.setToolTipDuration(-1)
        Form0.setStatusTip("")
        Form0.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form0)
        self.pushButton_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 130, 75, 25))
        self.pushButton_1.setObjectName("pushButton_1")

        self.retranslateUi(Form0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form0)
        self.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(self.passinon)
        ui_kata11.Calc_Button.clicked.connect(ui_kata11.passingInformation)
        ui_kata11.Clear_Button.clicked.connect(ui_kata11.clear_Data)

    def passinon(self):
        Form12.show()
        Form11.show()

    def retranslateUi(self, Form0):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form0.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton_1.setText(_translate("Form", "Ката"))


# Run main loop
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Form0 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui0 = Ui_Form0()
    ui0.setupUi0(Form0)
    Form0.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Файл "Kata"**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QLabel

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer

class KataSecondWindow_Ui(object):
    def setupUi_Kata2(self, Form12):
        Form12.setObjectName("Form")
        Form12.setEnabled(True)
        Form12.resize(1920, 1080)
        Form12.setWindowOpacity(1.0)
        Form12.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")

        self.label_sum2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form12)
        self.input_referee1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form12)
        self.input_referee2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form12)
        self.input_referee3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form12)
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form12)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form12)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form12)

        self.label_sum2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1090, 50, 760, 550))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_sum2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_sum2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gotham")
        font.setPointSize(250)

        self.label_sum2.setFont(font)
        self.label_sum2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.label_sum2.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label_sum2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label_sum2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.label_sum2.setLineWidth(1)
        self.label_sum2.setMidLineWidth(0)
        self.label_sum2.setScaledContents(False)
        self.label_sum2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_sum2.setObjectName("label_sum2")

        self.label_1.setEnabled(True)
        self.label_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 680, 250, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gotham")
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.label_1.setStyleSheet("color: grey")
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_1.setFont(font)
        self.label_1.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")

        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(325, 680, 250, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gotham")
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: grey")
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(580, 680, 250, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gotham")
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: grey")
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")

        self.input_referee1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 740, 250, 250))
        self.input_referee1.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.input_referee1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.input_referee1.setObjectName("input_referee1")

        self.input_referee2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(325, 740, 250, 250))
        self.input_referee2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.input_referee2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.input_referee2.setObjectName("input_referee2")

        self.input_referee3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(580, 740, 250, 250))
        self.input_referee3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.input_referee3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.input_referee3.setObjectName("input_referee3")

        self.retranslateUi(Form12)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form12)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form12):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form12.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form12", " "))
        self.label_sum2.setText(_translate("Form12", ""))
        self.label_1.setText(_translate("Form12", "1"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form12", "3"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form12", "2"))
        self.input_referee2.setText(_translate("Form12", ""))
        self.input_referee1.setText(_translate("Form12", ""))
        self.input_referee3.setText(_translate("Form12", ""))


class KataSecondWindow(QWidget, KataSecondWindow_Ui):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi_Kata2(self)

    def Extream_Value(self):
        q1 = self.input_referee1.text()
        q2 = self.input_referee2.text()
        q3 = self.input_referee3.text()

        l = [q1, q2, q3]
        m = [num for num in l if num != '']
        try:
            if min(m) == self.input_referee1.text():
                self.input_referee1.setStyleSheet(
                    "background-color: white; font-family: Gotham; color: Grey; font-size: 100px; text-align : left")
            elif min(m) == self.input_referee2.text():
                self.input_referee2.setStyleSheet(
                    "background-color: white; font-family: Gotham; color: Grey; font-size: 100px; text-align : left")
            elif min(m) == self.input_referee3.text():
                self.input_referee3.setStyleSheet(
                    "background-color: white; font-family: Gotham; color: Grey; font-size: 100px; text-align : left")
            else:
                pass
            if max(m) == self.input_referee2.text():
                self.label_2.setText('2')
                self.input_referee2.setStyleSheet(
                    "background-color: white; font-family: Gotham; color: Grey; font-size: 100px; text-align : left")
            elif max(m) == self.input_referee1.text():
                self.label_1.setText('1')
                self.input_referee1.setStyleSheet(
                    "background-color: white; font-family: Gotham; color: Grey; font-size: 100px; text-align : left")
            elif max(m) == self.input_referee3.text():
                self.label_3.setText('3')
                self.input_referee3.setStyleSheet(
                    "background-color: white; font-family: Gotham; color: Grey; font-size: 100px; text-align : left")
            else:
                pass

        except ValueError:
            self.label_1.setText('1')
            self.label_2.setText('2')
            self.label_3.setText('3')

class KataMainWindow_Ui(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form11):
        Form11.setObjectName("Form2")
        Form11.setEnabled(True)
        Form11.resize(901, 500)
        Form11.setWindowOpacity(1.0)
        Form11.setToolTipDuration(-1)
        Form11.setStatusTip("")
        Form11.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")

        self.MenuButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form11)
        self.MenuButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 10, 75, 20))
        self.MenuButton.setObjectName("MenuButton")

        self.KumiteButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form11)
        self.KumiteButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(800, 10, 75, 20))
        self.KumiteButton.setObjectName("KumiteButton")

        self.Calc_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form11)
        self.Calc_Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 410, 130, 30))
        self.Calc_Button.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(62, 106, 225); font-family: Gotham;"
                                       "color: white; font-size: 15pt;")
        self.Calc_Button.setObjectName("Calc_Button")

        self.Clear_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form11)
        self.Clear_Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 410, 130, 30))
        self.Clear_Button.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(62, 106, 225); font-family: Gotham;"
                                       "color: white; font-size: 15pt;")
        self.Clear_Button.setObjectName("Clear_Button")

        self.heading_sum = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form11)
        self.heading_sum.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 0, 200, 20))
        self.heading_sum.setStyleSheet("font-family: Gotham; font-weight: bold; font-size: 15pt;")
        self.heading_sum.setObjectName("heading_sum")

        self.label_sum = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form11)
        self.label_sum.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 20, 300, 130))
        self.label_sum.setStyleSheet("font-family: Gotham; color: grey; font-size: 15pt;")
        self.label_sum.setObjectName("label_sum")

        self.referee_point = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form11)
        self.referee_point.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 180, 700, 90))
        self.referee_point.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.referee_point.setStyleSheet("font: 50pt;")
        self.referee_point.setObjectName("referee_point")

        self.label_help = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form11)
        self.label_help.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(335, 367, 250, 13))
        self.label_help.setStyleSheet("color: grey; font-size: 7;")
        self.label_help.setObjectName("label_help")

        self.lineEdit_referee1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form11)
        self.lineEdit_referee1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 300, 100, 60))
        self.lineEdit_referee1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242); font-family: Gotham; font: 35pt;")
        self.lineEdit_referee1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit_referee1.setInputMask('9,9')
        self.lineEdit_referee1.setText(str('0,0'))
        self.lineEdit_referee1.setObjectName("lineEdit_referee1")

        self.lineEdit_referee2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form11)
        self.lineEdit_referee2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 300, 100, 60))
        self.lineEdit_referee2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242); font-family: Gotham; font: 35pt;")
        self.lineEdit_referee2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit_referee2.setInputMask('9,9')
        self.lineEdit_referee2.setText(str('0,0'))
        self.lineEdit_referee2.setObjectName("lineEdit_referee2")

        self.lineEdit_referee3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form11)
        self.lineEdit_referee3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 300, 100, 60))
        self.lineEdit_referee3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242); font-family: Gotham; font: 35pt;")
        self.lineEdit_referee3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit_referee3.setInputMask('9,9')
        self.lineEdit_referee3.setText(str('0,0'))
        self.lineEdit_referee3.setObjectName("lineEdit_referee3")

        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form11)
        self.label_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 280, 100, 13))
        self.label_1.setStyleSheet("color: grey; font-family: Gotham; font: 10pt;")
        self.label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form11)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 280, 100, 13))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: grey; font-family: Gotham; font: 10pt;")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form11)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 280, 100, 13))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: grey; font-family: Gotham; font: 10pt;")
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")

        self.retranslateUi(Form11)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form11)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form11):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form11.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form11", "Form"))
        self.MenuButton.setText(_translate("Form11", "Главное меню"))
        self.KumiteButton.setText(_translate("Form11", "Кумите"))
        self.Clear_Button.setText(_translate("Form11", "Очистить"))
        self.Calc_Button.setText(_translate("Form11", "Рассчитать"))
        self.heading_sum.setText(_translate("Form11", "Сумма балов"))
        self.label_sum.setText(_translate("Form11", "Нажми кнопку «Рассчитать»"))
        self.referee_point.setText(_translate("Form11", "Оценки судей"))
        self.label_help.setText(_translate("Form11", "Переключайся между судьями кнопкой Tab"))
        self.label_1.setText(_translate("Form11", "1 судья"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form11", "2 судья"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form11", "3 судья"))


class KataMainWindow(QWidget, KataMainWindow_Ui):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.KataSecondWindow = KataSecondWindow()

        self.Calc_Button.clicked.connect(self.passingInformation)
        self.Clear_Button.clicked.connect(self.clear_Data)

    def passingInformation(self):
        self.KataSecondWindow.label_1.setText('1')
        self.KataSecondWindow.label_2.setText('2')
        self.KataSecondWindow.label_3.setText('3')

        self.label_sum.setStyleSheet('font-family: Gotham; font: 90pt; color: rgb(0, 178, 80);')
        self.KataSecondWindow.input_referee1.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: white; font-family: Gotham; color: black; font-size: 135px; text-align: left")
        self.KataSecondWindow.input_referee2.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: white; font-family: Gotham; color: black; font-size: 135px; text-align: left")
        self.KataSecondWindow.input_referee3.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: white; font-family: Gotham; color: black; font-size: 135px; text-align: left")
        q1 = self.lineEdit_referee1.text()
        q2 = self.lineEdit_referee2.text()
        q3 = self.lineEdit_referee3.text()

        l = [q1, q2, q3]
        e = []

        for n in l:
            if n == ',':
                e.append(0.0)
            else:
                e.append(n.replace(",", "."))
        l = e
        newlst = [float(x) for x in l]

        m = newlst
        m = [num for num in m if num != 0]
        m_tuple = tuple(newlst)

        if len(m) < 3:
            self.label_sum.setStyleSheet("font-family: Gotham; font: 15pt; color: red")
            self.label_sum.setText('введи оценки судей')
            self.KataSecondWindow.label_sum2.setText('')
        else:
            m.remove(max(m))
            m.remove(min(m))
            m1 = round(sum(m), 1)  # +++ round
            m2 = str(m1).replace(".", ",")
            self.label_sum.setText(m2)
            l1 = str(m_tuple[0])
            self.lineEdit_referee1.setText(l1)
            self.KataSecondWindow.label_sum2.setText(self.label_sum.text().replace(",", "."))

        n_tuple = list(m_tuple)
        for num in range(len(n_tuple)):
            if n_tuple[0] == 0.0:
                n_tuple[0] = ''
                self.KataSecondWindow.label_1.setText('')
            elif n_tuple[1] == 0.0:
                n_tuple[1] = ''
                self.KataSecondWindow.label_2.setText('')
            elif n_tuple[2] == 0.0:
                n_tuple[2] = ''
                self.KataSecondWindow.label_3.setText('')

        self.KataSecondWindow.input_referee1.setText(str(n_tuple[0]))
        self.KataSecondWindow.input_referee2.setText(str(n_tuple[1]))
        self.KataSecondWindow.input_referee3.setText(str(n_tuple[2]))

        self.KataSecondWindow.Extream_Value()

    def clear_Data(self):
        self.label_sum.setText("Нажми кнопку «Рассчитать»")
        self.label_sum.setStyleSheet("font-family: Gotham; color: grey; font-size: 15pt;")
        self.lineEdit_referee1.setText('0,0')
        self.lineEdit_referee2.setText('0,0')
        self.lineEdit_referee3.setText('0,0')

        self.KataSecondWindow.label_sum2.setText('')
        self.KataSecondWindow.input_referee1.setText('')
        self.KataSecondWindow.input_referee2.setText('')
        self.KataSecondWindow.input_referee3.setText('')
        self.KataSecondWindow.label_1.setText('1')
        self.KataSecondWindow.label_2.setText('2')
        self.KataSecondWindow.label_3.setText('3')
```

В файле "**Kata**" не срабатывает строчка:

**320** - отправка текста в `Окно для отображения информации` в суммой баллов

**326, 329, 332** - заменяет текст в `Окне для отображения информации` с "1, 2, 3" на пустоту - ""

**334, 335, 336** - отправка текста в `Окно для отображения информации` введенных в окне оператора ввода

**347 - 353** - должны удаляться значения, введенные ранее в `Окне для отображения информации`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я отметил для вас строки, в которые внес изменения. Я не проверял вашу логику расчетов.

**q1260383_mail.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from q1260383_Kata import KataMainWindow                                    # !!!
#from q1260383_Kata import KataMainWindow_Ui
#from q1260383_Kata import KataSecondWindow
#from q1260383_Kata import KataSecondWindow_Ui

''' нет, нет и еще раз НЕТ
# Create application
#app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
# Create form and init UI Kata
Form11 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
ui_kata12 = KataMainWindow_Ui()
ui_kata12.setupUi(Form11)
ui_kata11 = KataMainWindow()
ui_kata11.setupUi(Form11)

Form12 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
ui_kata21 = KataSecondWindow_Ui()
ui_kata21.setupUi_Kata2(Form12)
ui_kata22 = KataSecondWindow()
ui_kata22.setupUi_Kata2(Form12)
'''

class Ui_Form0(object):
    def setupUi0(self, Form0):
        Form0.setObjectName("Form00")
        Form0.setEnabled(True)
        Form0.resize(400, 200)
        Form0.setWindowOpacity(1.0)
        Form0.setToolTipDuration(-1)
        Form0.setStatusTip("")
        Form0.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form0)
        self.pushButton_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 130, 75, 25))
        self.pushButton_1.setObjectName("pushButton_1")

        self.retranslateUi(Form0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form0)

# НИКОГДА НЕ изменяйте код, сгенерированный Qt Designer.
#        self.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(self.passinon)
#        ui_kata11.Calc_Button.clicked.connect(ui_kata11.passingInformation)
#        ui_kata11.Clear_Button.clicked.connect(ui_kata11.clear_Data)

#    def passinon(self):
#        Form12.show()
#        Form11.show()

    def retranslateUi(self, Form0):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form0.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton_1.setText(_translate("Form", "Ката"))


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
# Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, 
# и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.
class MailWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form0):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi0(self)

        self.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(self.passinon)
       
        self.ui_kata11 = KataMainWindow()
        self.ui_kata11.Calc_Button.clicked.connect(self.ui_kata11.passingInformation)
        self.ui_kata11.Clear_Button.clicked.connect(self.ui_kata11.clear_Data)
        
    def passinon(self):
        self.ui_kata11.show()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)    
#    Form0 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    w = MailWindow()
    w.show()

#    ui0 = Ui_Form0()
#    ui0.setupUi0(Form0)
#    Form0.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1260383_Kata.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QLabel

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer

class KataSecondWindow_Ui(object):
    def setupUi_Kata2(self, Form12):
        Form12.setObjectName("Form")
        Form12.setEnabled(True)
#        Form12.resize(1920, 1080)
        Form12.resize(1220, 680)                                     # поставьте свое

        Form12.setWindowOpacity(1.0)
        Form12.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")

        self.label_sum2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form12)
        self.input_referee1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form12)
        self.input_referee2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form12)
        self.input_referee3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form12)
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form12)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form12)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form12)

        self.label_sum2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 50, 760, 550))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_sum2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_sum2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gotham")
        font.setPointSize(250)

        self.label_sum2.setFont(font)
        self.label_sum2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.label_sum2.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.label_sum2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.label_sum2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.label_sum2.setLineWidth(1)
        self.label_sum2.setMidLineWidth(0)
        self.label_sum2.setScaledContents(False)
        self.label_sum2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_sum2.setObjectName("label_sum2")

        self.label_1.setEnabled(True)
        self.label_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 280, 250, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gotham")
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.label_1.setStyleSheet("color: grey")
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_1.setFont(font)
        self.label_1.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")

        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(325, 280, 250, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gotham")
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: grey")
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(580, 280, 250, 50))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gotham")
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: grey")
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom | QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")

        self.input_referee1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 340, 250, 250))
        self.input_referee1.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.input_referee1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.input_referee1.setObjectName("input_referee1")

        self.input_referee2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(325, 340, 250, 250))
        self.input_referee2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.input_referee2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.input_referee2.setObjectName("input_referee2")

        self.input_referee3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(580, 340, 250, 250))
        self.input_referee3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.input_referee3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.input_referee3.setObjectName("input_referee3")

        self.retranslateUi(Form12)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form12)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form12):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form12.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form12", " "))
        self.label_sum2.setText(_translate("Form12", "sum"))
        self.label_1.setText(_translate("Form12", "1"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form12", "3"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form12", "2"))
        self.input_referee2.setText(_translate("Form12", "referee2"))
        self.input_referee1.setText(_translate("Form12", "referee1"))
        self.input_referee3.setText(_translate("Form12", "referee3"))


class KataSecondWindow(QWidget, KataSecondWindow_Ui):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi_Kata2(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Kata Second Window')
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_1, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_3, 0, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.input_referee1, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.input_referee2, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.input_referee3, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_sum2, 0, 3, 3, 3)
        
''' что это ???
    def Extream_Value(self):
        q1 = self.input_referee1.text()
        q2 = self.input_referee2.text()
        q3 = self.input_referee3.text()

        l = [q1, q2, q3]
        m = [num for num in l if num != '']
        try:
            if min(m) == self.input_referee1.text():
                self.input_referee1.setStyleSheet(
                    "background-color: white; font-family: Gotham; color: Grey; font-size: 100px; text-align : left")
            elif min(m) == self.input_referee2.text():
                self.input_referee2.setStyleSheet(
                    "background-color: white; font-family: Gotham; color: Grey; font-size: 100px; text-align : left")
            elif min(m) == self.input_referee3.text():
                self.input_referee3.setStyleSheet(
                    "background-color: white; font-family: Gotham; color: Grey; font-size: 100px; text-align : left")
            else:
                pass
            if max(m) == self.input_referee2.text():
                self.label_2.setText('2')
                self.input_referee2.setStyleSheet(
                    "background-color: white; font-family: Gotham; color: Grey; font-size: 100px; text-align : left")
            elif max(m) == self.input_referee1.text():
                self.label_1.setText('1')
                self.input_referee1.setStyleSheet(
                    "background-color: white; font-family: Gotham; color: Grey; font-size: 100px; text-align : left")
            elif max(m) == self.input_referee3.text():
                self.label_3.setText('3')
                self.input_referee3.setStyleSheet(
                    "background-color: white; font-family: Gotham; color: Grey; font-size: 100px; text-align : left")
            else:
                pass

        except ValueError:
            self.label_1.setText('1')
            self.label_2.setText('2')
            self.label_3.setText('3')
'''


class KataMainWindow_Ui(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form11):
        Form11.setObjectName("Form2")
        Form11.setEnabled(True)
        Form11.resize(901, 500)
        Form11.setWindowOpacity(1.0)
        Form11.setToolTipDuration(-1)
        Form11.setStatusTip("")
        Form11.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")

        self.MenuButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form11)
        self.MenuButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 10, 75, 20))
        self.MenuButton.setObjectName("MenuButton")

        self.KumiteButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form11)
        self.KumiteButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(800, 10, 75, 20))
        self.KumiteButton.setObjectName("KumiteButton")

        self.Calc_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form11)
        self.Calc_Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 410, 130, 30))
        self.Calc_Button.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(62, 106, 225); font-family: Gotham;"
                                       "color: white; font-size: 15pt;")
        self.Calc_Button.setObjectName("Calc_Button")

        self.Clear_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form11)
        self.Clear_Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 410, 130, 30))
        self.Clear_Button.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(62, 106, 225); font-family: Gotham;"
                                       "color: white; font-size: 15pt;")
        self.Clear_Button.setObjectName("Clear_Button")

        self.heading_sum = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form11)
        self.heading_sum.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 0, 200, 20))
        self.heading_sum.setStyleSheet("font-family: Gotham; font-weight: bold; font-size: 15pt;")
        self.heading_sum.setObjectName("heading_sum")

        self.label_sum = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form11)
        self.label_sum.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 20, 300, 130))
        self.label_sum.setStyleSheet("font-family: Gotham; color: grey; font-size: 15pt;")
        self.label_sum.setObjectName("label_sum")

        self.referee_point = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form11)
        self.referee_point.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 180, 700, 90))
        self.referee_point.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.referee_point.setStyleSheet("font: 50pt;")
        self.referee_point.setObjectName("referee_point")

        self.label_help = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form11)
        self.label_help.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(335, 367, 250, 13))
        self.label_help.setStyleSheet("color: grey; font-size: 7;")
        self.label_help.setObjectName("label_help")

        self.lineEdit_referee1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form11)
        self.lineEdit_referee1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 300, 100, 60))
        self.lineEdit_referee1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242); font-family: Gotham; font: 35pt;")
        self.lineEdit_referee1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit_referee1.setInputMask('9,9')
        self.lineEdit_referee1.setText(str('0,0'))
        self.lineEdit_referee1.setObjectName("lineEdit_referee1")

        self.lineEdit_referee2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form11)
        self.lineEdit_referee2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 300, 100, 60))
        self.lineEdit_referee2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242); font-family: Gotham; font: 35pt;")
        self.lineEdit_referee2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit_referee2.setInputMask('9,9')
        self.lineEdit_referee2.setText(str('0,0'))
        self.lineEdit_referee2.setObjectName("lineEdit_referee2")

        self.lineEdit_referee3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form11)
        self.lineEdit_referee3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 300, 100, 60))
        self.lineEdit_referee3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242); font-family: Gotham; font: 35pt;")
        self.lineEdit_referee3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit_referee3.setInputMask('9,9')
        self.lineEdit_referee3.setText(str('0,0'))
        self.lineEdit_referee3.setObjectName("lineEdit_referee3")

        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form11)
        self.label_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 280, 100, 13))
        self.label_1.setStyleSheet("color: grey; font-family: Gotham; font: 10pt;")
        self.label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form11)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 280, 100, 13))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: grey; font-family: Gotham; font: 10pt;")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form11)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 280, 100, 13))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("color: grey; font-family: Gotham; font: 10pt;")
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")

        self.retranslateUi(Form11)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form11)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form11):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form11.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form11", "Form"))
        self.MenuButton.setText(_translate("Form11", "Главное меню"))
        self.KumiteButton.setText(_translate("Form11", "Кумите"))
        self.Clear_Button.setText(_translate("Form11", "Очистить"))
        self.Calc_Button.setText(_translate("Form11", "Рассчитать"))
        self.heading_sum.setText(_translate("Form11", "Сумма балов"))
        self.label_sum.setText(_translate("Form11", "Нажми кнопку «Рассчитать»"))
        self.referee_point.setText(_translate("Form11", "Оценки судей"))
        self.label_help.setText(_translate("Form11", "Переключайся между судьями кнопкой Tab"))
        self.label_1.setText(_translate("Form11", "1 судья"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form11", "2 судья"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form11", "3 судья"))


class KataMainWindow(QWidget, KataMainWindow_Ui):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Kata MainWindow')

# 
#       self.KataSecondWindow = KataSecondWindow()
#            ^
#            v
        self.kataSecondWindow = KataSecondWindow()

# -       self.Calc_Button.clicked.connect(self.passingInformation)
# -       self.Clear_Button.clicked.connect(self.clear_Data)

    def passingInformation(self):
        ''' ???
        self.KataSecondWindow.label_1.setText('1')
        self.KataSecondWindow.label_2.setText('2')
        self.KataSecondWindow.label_3.setText('3')
        '''
        self.label_sum.setStyleSheet('font-family: Gotham; font: 90pt; color: rgb(0, 178, 80);')
        self.kataSecondWindow.input_referee1.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: white; font-family: Gotham; color: black; font-size: 135px; text-align: left")
        self.kataSecondWindow.input_referee2.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: white; font-family: Gotham; color: black; font-size: 135px; text-align: left")
        self.kataSecondWindow.input_referee3.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: white; font-family: Gotham; color: black; font-size: 135px; text-align: left")
        
        q1 = self.lineEdit_referee1.text()
        q2 = self.lineEdit_referee2.text()
        q3 = self.lineEdit_referee3.text()

        l = [q1, q2, q3]
        e = []

        for n in l:
            if n == ',':
                e.append(0.0)
            else:
                e.append(n.replace(",", "."))
        l = e
        newlst = [float(x) for x in l]

        m = newlst
        m = [num for num in m if num != 0]
        m_tuple = tuple(newlst)

        if len(m) < 3:
            self.label_sum.setStyleSheet("font-family: Gotham; font: 15pt; color: red")
            self.label_sum.setText('введи оценки судей')
            
            self.kataSecondWindow.hide()
            return
# -           self.KataSecondWindow.label_sum2.setText('')
        else:
            m.remove(max(m))
            m.remove(min(m))
            m1 = round(sum(m), 1)         # +++ round
            m2 = str(m1).replace(".", ",")
            self.label_sum.setText(m2)
            l1 = str(m_tuple[0])
            self.lineEdit_referee1.setText(l1)
# -           self.KataSecondWindow.label_sum2.setText(self.label_sum.text().replace(",", "."))

        n_tuple = list(m_tuple)
        for num in range(len(n_tuple)):
            if n_tuple[0] == 0.0:
                n_tuple[0] = ''
# -               self.KataSecondWindow.label_1.setText('')
            elif n_tuple[1] == 0.0:
                n_tuple[1] = ''
# -               self.KataSecondWindow.label_2.setText('')
            elif n_tuple[2] == 0.0:
                n_tuple[2] = ''
# -               self.KataSecondWindow.label_3.setText('')

#            v
        self.kataSecondWindow.input_referee1.setText(str(n_tuple[0]))
        self.kataSecondWindow.input_referee2.setText(str(n_tuple[1]))
        self.kataSecondWindow.input_referee3.setText(str(n_tuple[2]))
# -       self.KataSecondWindow.Extream_Value()

        self.kataSecondWindow.label_sum2.setText(self.label_sum.text().replace(",", "."))
# Внимание        
        self.kataSecondWindow.show()                                                 # +++

    def clear_Data(self):
        self.label_sum.setText("Нажми кнопку «Рассчитать»")
        self.label_sum.setStyleSheet("font-family: Gotham; color: grey; font-size: 15pt;")
        self.lineEdit_referee1.setText('0,0')
        self.lineEdit_referee2.setText('0,0')
        self.lineEdit_referee3.setText('0,0')
# Внимание
        self.kataSecondWindow.hide()                                                 # +++
        '''  ???
        self.KataSecondWindow.label_sum2.setText('')
        self.KataSecondWindow.input_referee1.setText('')
        self.KataSecondWindow.input_referee2.setText('')
        self.KataSecondWindow.input_referee3.setText('')
        self.KataSecondWindow.label_1.setText('1')
        self.KataSecondWindow.label_2.setText('2')
        self.KataSecondWindow.label_3.setText('3')
        '''
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ник, спасибо большое! Накашмарил я там кода, просто жуть! ОГРОМНЕЙШЕЕ СПАСИБО!

Comment: @dutik пожалуйста